# Can we set retention period for a table in years in Kusto?

Tags: bigdata, azure-data-explorer, kql

Currently, I can see only examples using the retention period specified in days. Can we specify the retention period of a table in years in Kusto? I mean will the below command sets the retention period to 10 years?
`.alter-merge table Table1 policy retention softdelete = 10y recoverability = disabled`

Also, soft delete keeps the data in DB and marks the record as deleted right. Is there a way to do hard delete and any issues with using it? My records do not refer to old data and hence I want to completely delete the records after the retention period.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The retention policy command receives a [timespan literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/timespan#timespan-literals) and `year` is not one of the supported formats, so the command in your example does not work. You need to specify the period in days.
- If `Recoverability` is set to `Enabled`, the storage artifacts will be deleted from storage 14 days after retention policy expires. If it is set to `Disabled` deletion will be done 1d after retention policy period.